# Anaconda: Pandas Datareader - Module not found

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, python-import, pandas-datareader

Solution: was using jupyter notebook on windows, so never able to connect to the env/kernel. Loaded up the anaconda environment in pycharm and everything works now

I'm using Anaconda and the jupyter notebook but I'm constantly getting an error trying to import pandas datareader and keep getting the ModuleNotFoundError for some reason.

I tried to reinstall pandas-datareader several times with several install methods (regular, via site link, pip install) while being in the active environment.

I tried downgrading my Python version down to 3.6.0 but getting the same error for all of them.

I also checked the folder in the environment at /Lib/site-packages and both folders (pandas_datareader and pandas_datareader-0.5.0.dist-info) are located there.

Don't really know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1fbb66132a8a> in <module>()
      3 from matplotlib import style
      4 import pandas as pd
----> 5 import pandas_datareader.data as web

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'



# packages in environment at C:\Users\....\Anaconda3\envs\finance:
#
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py36hd4cc5e8_1
ca-certificates           2017.08.26           h94faf87_0    anaconda
certifi                   2017.11.5        py36hb8ac631_0    anaconda
cffi                      1.11.4           py36hfa6e2cd_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h420ce6e_1
cryptography              2.1.4            py36he1d7878_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
freetype                  2.8              vc14h17c9bdf_0  [vc14]  anaconda
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0
icu                       58.2             vc14hc45fdbb_0  [vc14]  anaconda
idna                      2.6              py36h148d497_1
intel-openmp              2018.0.0             hd92c6cd_8
jpeg                      9b               vc14h4d7706e_1  [vc14]  anaconda
libpng                    1.6.32           vc14h5163883_3  [vc14]  anaconda
matplotlib                2.1.1            py36h2062329_0
mkl                       2018.0.1             h2108138_4
numpy                     1.14.0           py36h4a99626_0
openssl                   1.0.2n               h74b6da3_0    anaconda
pandas                    0.22.0           py36h6538335_0
pandas-datareader         0.5.0                    py36_0    anaconda
pip                       9.0.1            py36h226ae91_4
pycparser                 2.18             py36hd053e01_1
pyopenssl                 17.5.0           py36h5b7d817_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36h785a196_1
pyqt                      5.6.0            py36hb5ed885_5
pysocks                   1.6.7            py36h698d350_1
python                    3.6.4                h6538335_1
python-dateutil           2.6.1            py36h509ddcb_1
pytz                      2017.3           py36h1d3fa6b_0
qt                        5.6.2           vc14h6f8c307_12  [vc14]  anaconda
requests                  2.18.4           py36h4371aae_1
requests-file             1.4.1                    py36_0
requests-ftp              0.3.1                    py36_0
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36h53aea1b_0
scipy                     1.0.0            py36h1260518_0
setuptools                38.4.0                   py36_0
sip                       4.18.1           py36h9c25514_2
six                       1.11.0           py36h4db2310_1
sqlite                    3.20.1           vc14h7ce8c62_1  [vc14]  anaconda
tornado                   4.5.3                    py36_0
urllib3                   1.22             py36h276f60a_0
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
wheel                     0.30.0           py36h6c3ec14_1
win_inet_pton             1.0.1            py36he67d7fd_1
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
```

Comment: Did you try this mentor: conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader?

Comment: Yes I tried that. Just checked again to be sure because I doubted I uninstalled datareader first when I tried it initially, but that did not fix it. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that /Lib/site-packages is not in your PYTHONPATH. See: 
https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

"sys.path is populated using the current working directory, followed by directories listed in your PYTHONPATH environment variable, followed by installation-dependent default paths, which are controlled by the site module."

TLDR: Make sure that /Lib/site-packages/ is in your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Just found the issue. I was using jupyter notebook on windows so I coudn't connect to the kernel and was working never working in the environment, the previous script I wrote I had no issues so never noticed and could have sworn I was able to select the environment in jupyter when I created it so never tought this might have been the issue. Switched to pycharm and loaded the anaconda environment in there and everything works now.